# Neutron Openvswitch, cant bridge over external nic (Profitbricks) losing connection

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openstack, openstack-neutron, openvswitch

I am following the official Openstack Juno Guide for Ubuntu 14.04. Now i stuck at adding a port to the external NIC to bridge the traffic. I get my IP for this Interface by dhcp (Server is a Vserver from profitbricks). I also found serveral people with the same issue, but they all fixed it, because they got different setups.

After making the changes in the neutron configs, i have to add the internal and ex bridge and after that adding the port to the external nic

```
ovs-vsctl add-br br-ex

ovs-vsctl add-port br-ex eth1 (in my case the external nic)
```

After i set the port, the connection to the Server gets lost. So i tried...

```
ovs-vsctl del-port br-ex eth1
ifconfig br-ex x.x.x.x && ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0
ovs-vsctl add-port br-ex eth1
```

This didnt helped. Then i changed the interfaces and changed the eth1 to manual and gave the adress to br-ex, but that didnt helped also ... after reboot the eth1 becomes senseless and i still have no connectivity.

The Bridge has been commented to give internet access back.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto br-ex
#iface br-ex inet static
#address 185.48.xx.xx
#netmask 255.255.255.255
#broadcast 185.48.xx.xx
#gateway 185.48.x.x
#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp #here i switched to manual

allow-hotplug eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eth3
iface eth3 inet dhcp
```

Openstack made so many changes that every manual from the older versions seems legit and still so false... I have no clue why it stucks at this step, while the bridge is taking the config from eth1.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend trying to use a static IP address instead of the DHCP assigned IP address. It does appears the static IP assigned has the wrong netmask specified in your example:

```
#netmask 255.255.255.255
```

When switching a VM to a static IP on the ProfitBricks platform, I would suggest confirming the following items.

1. Make sure the NIC within the DCD has DHCP disabled (unchecked) for the correct server NIC. Also, note the gateway IP address in case it has changed.
2. The DHCP IP address assigned through ProfitBricks will use the 255.255.255.255 (32) subnet mask. If you switch to a static IP, then that IP and the specified gateway IP in the DCD must be on the subnet. So you will likely need to adjust the subnet mask to 255.255.255.0 (24).
3. Finally, confirm the MAC address specified for the NIC in the DCD matches the MAC address of the NIC within Linux. If those do not match, there will be problems with connectivity.

Comment: yep ... actually ive done all of that already. The MAC is not matching. And thats why OVS wont gather the IP-Config. Profitbricks just said, that they cant handle different MAC-Adresses than the one they set. So they told me i have to workaround it myself by using OpenFlow and make a rule to "sniff" the DHCP-Packets from the physical external nic and translate the MAC.

Comment: Can the MAC address of the bridge be changed similar to that of a normal interface? `iface br-ex inet static` followed by `hwaddress ether 01:02:03:04:05:06` on the next line?

Comment: i dont think thats possible. or might need deeper hacking into the system. like taking the mac from the physical interface and give it to the bridge, but ive never done this before...
BTW. The netmask is the same as the external NIC is using.